# Woocommerce - how to provide upgrades to purchased products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My woocommerce site sells digital products.

When I provide a bugfix or a new version, I would like to give automatic upgrades to existing customers.

It appears that I will need to create an order with the a 100% "discount", so as to enable access and downloading for each customer.

However, I have been unable to find a concrete example on how to create an order programmatically, add products to it, update values and save it as completed - in a correct manner so that all custom hooks and filters are called correctly.

Is there a complete tutorial available anywhere ?
Has someone already done this kind of thing ?

Comment: [EDD Software licensing](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/downloads/software-licensing/) and [Woothemes Software Add-on](https://www.woothemes.com/products/software-add-on/) should handle this.

Comment: Thank you @helgatheviking. After having looked at these two solutions, neither match my needs. My licensing needs are already implemented. My need is only upgrade/update management, which is why I need to implement this "manually". Hence the question here.

Comment: I still don't think this should be "manual". 1. You will litter your database with unnecessary empty orders and 2. you add steps to the update process, which ensures more users will have out of date code. If you already have the licensing sorted then I would suggest looking at providing plugin updates from a 3rd party host (ie: *not* wp.org) which would allow your plugin to be updated in the admin just like any other.

Comment: This question has popped up [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/update-plugin-from-personal-api) and Ipstenu has a pretty good [list of update options]( http://halfelf.org/2014/self-update-your-plugins/)

Comment: This is probably very good for plugins etc, but I am not doing plugins.  This is for an application.

Comment: Ah ok. If the product is downloadable from your own site, then I think that if you update the product's downloadable file that the new version will be available in the Downloads section of My Account. Otherwise, I think you are looking at custom development.

Comment: Totally agree that this requires a custom development - which is why I asked this question !